# Full-text search on SQL Server has case-sensitive behavior

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, case-sensitive

I have a full-text index with an empty stoplist.

The table contains a row with the value 'A. Beta'. If I search for 'A. Beta' or 'A. beta' (using full-text search) the row shows up correctly. But if I search for 'a. Beta' or 'a. beta' the row does not show up.

What is happening? Is there a good workaround to this? I could remove full stops from the search string before sending it to the database, but is there anything else I should remove?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST empty_stoplist;
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG mytable_catalog;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable (
        name Language 1033
    )
    KEY INDEX mytable_pk
    ON mytable_catalog;
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable SET STOPLIST empty_stoplist;
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable START UPDATE POPULATION;

INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('A. Beta');

-- Wait until indexing is complete

SELECT * FROM mytable mt WHERE CONTAINS(mt.*, '"A. Beta"');
-- 1 result
SELECT * FROM mytable mt WHERE CONTAINS(mt.*, '"A. beta"');
-- 1 result
SELECT * FROM mytable mt WHERE CONTAINS(mt.*, '"a. Beta"');
-- 0 results
SELECT * FROM mytable mt WHERE CONTAINS(mt.*, '"a. beta"');
-- 0 results
```

Running the fts parser on 'A. Beta' and 'a. Beta' gives different results. This might be related:

```
-- Replace 7 with the id of 'empty_stoplist' or use NULL instead (same result).
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"A. Beta"', 1033, 7, 0)
-- keyword             group_id    phrase_id   occurrence  special_term     display_term  expansion_type  source_term
-- 0x0061              1           0           1           Exact Match      a             0               A. Beta
-- 0x0062006500740061  1           0           2           Exact Match      beta          0               A. Beta
```

vs.

```
-- Replace 7 with the id of 'empty_stoplist' or use NULL instead (same result).
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"a. Beta"', 1033, 7, 0)
-- keyword             group_id    phrase_id   occurrence   special_term     display_term  expansion_type  source_term
-- 0x0061              1           0           1            Exact Match      a             0               a. Beta
-- 0xFF                1           0           9            End Of Sentence  END OF FILE   0               a. Beta
-- 0x0062006500740061  1           0           10           Exact Match      beta          0               a. Beta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually not with case sensitivity but with the period in `a. Beta` which the full text parser is interpreting as "end of sentence". In other words, the parser correctly interprets `A.` (uppercase) as an abbreviation and ignores the period but it thinks `a.` (lowercase) is the end of a sentence instead of an abbreviation since abbreviations are typically capitalized in English. The full text engine uses end-of-sentence markers as well as end-of-paragraph markers when counting word occurrences to avoid false positives when matching quoted phrases. (I don't know much else about how occurrence counting works other than this vague statement from [How Search Query Results Are Ranked](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142524(v=sql.105).aspx): *In order to avoid false positives in phrase and proximity queries, end-of-sentence and end-of-paragraph introduce larger occurrence gaps.*)

The easiest way to work around this problem is to remove periods from the search string. You will find that both of these searches will return the 1 result you are looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable mt WHERE CONTAINS(mt.*, '"A Beta"');

SELECT * FROM mytable mt WHERE CONTAINS(mt.*, '"a Beta"');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) :

> Full-text queries **are not case-sensitive**. For example, searching for "Aluminum" or "aluminum" returns the same results.

The problem is related to the search condition and how the query is parsed, as answered by @Keith.